# Can a shell script tell what directory it's in. No bashisms

Tags: shell, sh

Inspired by this question.

[Getting the source directory of a Bash script from within](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in)

Is it possible, but without the need for bash.

I'm running Ubuntu and before i needed that accepted solution from the Bash question, my hash bang was like this

```
#!/bin/sh
```

and I liked it that way, is there a way to keep it that way?

EDIT:

It should output the correct directory, even when run thus,

```
./script.sh
```

Comment: as far as I remember, /bin/sh is a symbolic link to /bin/bash. Therefore, the solution in your question is applied.

Comment: @silent: not on Ubuntu, where /bin/sh is Dash, which is a much simpler shell than Bash.  They changed this a year or two ago.

Comment: Ah, Ok. I don't know about that.

Comment: And not on a whole bunch of other systems, where /bin/sh could be, for example, a symlink to ksh, or an actual Bourne shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to do this in a reliable way without making assumptions about the system it's running on. This [bash wiki entry](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028) goes into a lot of detail about the issue.

The page offers these alternatives:

> It really makes the most sense to keep your script's configuration in
>   a single, static location such as /etc/foobar.conf. If you need to
>   define multiple configuration files, then you can have a directory
>   (say, /var/lib/foobar/ or /usr/local/lib/foobar/), and read that
>   directory's location from a fixed place such as /etc/foobar.conf. If
>   you don't even want that much to be hard-coded, you could pass the
>   location of foobar.conf (or of your configuration directory itself) as
>   a parameter to the script. If you need the script to assume certain
>   default in the absence of /etc/foobar.conf, you can put defaults in
>   the script itself, or fall back to something like $HOME/.foobar.conf
>   if /etc/foobar.conf is missing. When you install the script on a
>   target system, you could put the script's location into a variable in
>   the script itself. The information is available at that point, and as
>   long as the script doesn't move, it will always remain correct for
>   each installed system. In most cases, it makes more sense to abort
>   gracefully if your configuration data can't be found by obvious means,
>   rather than going through arcane processes and possibly coming up with
>   wrong answers.

Comment: Hmm, thought provoking answer. Thank you.

Comment: Other answers below do work for most cases, but it's still important to remember that there's no foolproof way for %100 of the situations. Good reference.

Answer (score 4):

How about `$(dirname -- "$0")`?

If your shell uses backticks only, it'd be:

```
`dirname -- "$0"`
```

Comment: That must be `$(dirname -- "$0")`, or you will run into errors.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the double-dash you suggest to avoid dirname interpreting the path as arguments.

Comment: `dirname` is not POSIX, and may not be available on all systems.

Comment: The OP uses Ubuntu, and dirname is surely on there.

Answer (score 3):

`/bin/sh` is a bourne-compatible shell (today either `bash` or `ksh`). On those, the following line of code will give you the absolute path of the currently running script:

```
DIR=$( cd $( dirname -- "$0" ) > /dev/null ; pwd )
```

There is a lot of wisdom in this line:

- The quotes make sure that spaces in the path don't cause problems.
- No quotes are necessary to protect the results of `$(...)`. If you use backticks, you need more quotes but almost any shell today supports `$()` because of the many problems with backticks.
- The `$()` has the nice side effect that the commands are executed in a subshell, so the current path doesn't change.
- The `--` is there to avoid problems with paths that start with `-`
- The `> /dev/null` is there because `cd` can print the current path depending on a shell option.
- I'm using `dirname` because everything else needs special features which aren't available everywhere. It means that a process has to be forked but then, this happens once.
- `pwd` prints the absolute path

Answer (score 2):

```
mydir="${0%/*}"
if [ "$mydir" == "$0" ]; then
    echo "Indeterminate location."
    exit 1;
fi;
```

No need to create an extra process and call `dirname`. Indetermine location can happen when running it directly within the shell prompt (where $0 == "-bash", for example), or when a program is invoked by searching through $PATH. (Then $0 will also be without slashes)

```
#optional addition
mydir=$(readlink -f "$0")
```

Comment: Do you think ${0%/*} works in Dash, the Ubuntu default shell the OP uses?

Comment: Yes, that is a POSIX parameter expansions. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02

Comment: `$0` is not reliable, and `readlink` is not available on every system

Comment: I didn't understand your answer, can you elaborate for me please?

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I use :

```
EXEC_DIR=$( readlink -f $( dirname -- "$0" ) )
```

in my shell scripts (/bin/sh). Works OK for me so far.

Comment: @Aaron thanks for the --, I was unaware of its existence and was looking for such a feature !

Answer (score 2):

For those who looking cross BASH DASH current script folder.

**1.sh**:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$BASH_SOURCE" != "" ]
then
    DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "$BASH_SOURCE" )" && pwd )"
elif [ "$DASH_SOURCE" != "" ]
then
    DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "$DASH_SOURCE" )" && pwd )"
else
    DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "$0" )" && pwd )"
fi
echo $DIR
```

Will produce the following:

```
cd ~
docker@boot2docker:~$ sh ./test/1.sh 
/home/docker/test
docker@boot2docker:~$ ./test/1.sh 
/home/docker/test
docker@boot2docker:~$ source ./test/1.sh 
/home/docker
```

If anybody knows how to deal with `source`, please comment below.